# Rigify not generating rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

[image]

So as you can see above is my rig setup:

> Four Legs

> One Tail

> Spine with a head bone

> Facial Bone [Ears and nose]

All of these except for the last one [ears and nose] was added from the rigify presets.
But every time i generate the rig, only the spine and tail gets setup, as seen here:

[image]

Why isn't it working? All of the bones are within one skeleton.

Also the tail bone can only curl and NOT move side to side or anything.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be one of two things.

Either you did not set up the necessary Rig Types at all... if you didn't then you need to learn more about Rigify.

Or you are experiencing a common Blender bug that makes bone properties disappear if you delete a bone and then recover it using ctrl+z.

Learn more about this issue here.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcGM14fa6E0

Comment: I feel this a lack of knowledge, could you tell me how set up the rig types? Barring which, point me out to tutorials or reading material?

Comment: The rig types are set in the Metarig in Pose Mode in the Bone tab. Usually they are in the first bone of a chain, e.g. the upper arm, the upper leg, the first spine bone etc.
I can recommend my own Rigify tutorials but keep in mind that they are meant to teach you Rigify, not to solve your particular problem. So it may take a while but once you are through with the course you will know how Rigify works! :)
This is my old series for 2.8
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJv68SSdwxip33M7snakl6Dx

Comment: And I started remaking it for 4.0 (currently not complete)
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJt1GvL-Fcxy-fPgEFG-1fLp
Hope this helps!

Comment: Your tutorials helped me a f-ton! Turns out hadn't set any rig type, as for the disconnection part, the rig required a "basic.super_copy" type between limbs as "parenting bridge". Thanks for the point out.

Comment: Nice, that's perfect!